# How to keyword search in "mongodb" for "typeahead" get call with user input as val?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, angular-ui-typeahead

This is what I am trying to achieve

I have an input field, on user input ,ajax call will be made to mongodb table and pull the json result for typeahead feature.

everything is working, but when data pulled using,using following function

```
   exports.index = function(req, res){
  Licmgt.find(function (err, licMgts) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    return res.json(200, licMgts);
  });
};
```

it brings all data on every key word pressed, so end result is, typeahead result never narrows down to the right string.

below is the code for type ahead call in html element

```
      <input class="form-control" typeahead="sourceArray as sourceArray for sourceArray in getOneID($viewValue)" 
  ng-model="asyncSelected" type="text">
      <i ng-show="oneid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" ></i>
```

and below the ajax call function

```
  $scope.getOneID = function(val){
    console.log("value is " + val);
    return $http.get('/api/licMgts/',{
      params: {
        OneID:val
      }
    }).then(function(res){
      var oneIDs =[];
      angular.forEach(res.data,function(item){
        oneIDs.push(item.OneID);
      });
      return oneIDs;
    });
  };
```

I would like to know how to query in mongo db with "like" option, for keyword search, I have found some answers like text search with $text, like below

```
db.collections.find({$text:{$search: /keyword/}})
```

is this the right way to go? any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have a query in your `Licmgt.find` as far as I can see just a callback so this will find all documents in the collection.

Comment: Are you implementing some sort of auto-complete feature?

Comment: Yes, I am trying implement typeahead feature,

Comment: You probaly want to use left-anchored [regular expressions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/), like `db.collection.find({ "field" : { "$regex" : /^typedSoFar/ } })`. With the anchor, MongoDB can use an index on `field` by automatically recasting the query as a range query.

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to use full text mongo search with like operator as such.
Since there are some hack the developer can do. 
The $text operator can search for words and phrases not part of the word.

"Running" can be in result of "run" (It is supported  by language)
"Blueberry" can be fetch when you search for "blue".